# Can anybody explain me this program I'm finding difficult to understand as i'm newbee to plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I'm trying to output a number accepted dynamically and print the number of digits in the number accepted

```
 WHILE N !=0
  LOOP

  R:=MOD(N,10);
  CNT:=CNT+1;
  N:=TRUNC(N/10);

  END LOOP;
```

I simply just want to know how it worked with proper understanding  I tried this  program with my logic and  i got what i needed but this source code is hard to understand and i want to know how this worked like  why is mod used in this code even though without making use of it i'm getting the right output ?? and why is trunc used here ??*

Comment: Try adding some `dbms_output.put_line(...)` to print the values of the variables.

Comment: Have you read up on what [mod](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions101.htm) and [trunc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions221.htm) do? We can't comment on the output as you haven't shown that, and what (if anything) you do with `R` and `CNT`.

Comment: @AlexPoole 

SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('no of digits of a given number is '||CNT);
This is the oupput can u explain me now ?

Comment: You don't do anything with `R` then, so assigning it is pointless, and the use of `mod` is redundant too. JuanCarlosOropeza has explained what the `trunc` is doing and how the loop works. It seems to be a variation on calculating the common (base-10) log of the starting value.

Answer (score 1):

This create a loop to see how many time you can divide the number by 10.

Let say `N = 1234`

Loop break condition is `N != 0` so enter the loop.

This isnt really necesary as you can see you dont use `R` anywhere else.

```
 R := MOD(N,10);
```

Then you count the first digit

```
 CNT:=CNT+1;
```

And

```
 N:=TRUNC(N/10); -- Return N = 123 instead of 123.4
```

With `CNT=2` return `N = 12`
With `CNT=3` return `N = 1`
With `CNT=4` return `N = 0`

and end the loop because `N == 0` returing `CNT = 4`.

Answer (score 1):

Reformatting and numbering your lines:

```
1. WHILE N !=0 LOOP
2.   R:=MOD(N,10);
3.   CNT:=CNT+1;
4.   N:=TRUNC(N/10);
5. END LOOP;
```

- Lines 1 & 5 will keep the loop going while `N` is non-zero (i.e. there are more digits).
- Line 2 will get the value of the least significant digit - however this is not used anywhere so the line can be ignored.
- Line 3 increments the count of the number of digits (I am assuming that `CNT` is declared somewhere earlier in the PL/SQL block).
- Line 4 divides the value by 10 and then uses `TRUNC()` to discard the fractional part of the result - if you did not discard the fractional part of the result then the loop would never terminate as, if `N != 0` then `N/10` will also never be zero.

A one-line method of performing the same calculation is to use logarithms:

```
CNT := CEIL( LOG( 10, ABS( N ) ) );
```

- `ABS()` gets the absolute value (i.e. ignores any negative signs)  of `N`
- `LOG( 10, N )` gets the logarithm, base 10, of `N`
- `CEIL()` rounds up any fractional parts to give a whole number.